# Why can't variables defined in a conditional be constructed with arguments?

Tags: c++

The question is simple.  Why does this compile:

```
bool b(true);
if (b) { /* */ }
```

And this compile:

```
if (bool b = true) { /* */ }
```

But not this:

```
if (bool b(true)) { /* */ }
```

In my real code, I need to construct an object and test it, while also having it destroyed when the if-block ends.  Basically, I'm looking for something like this:

```
{
    Dingus dingus(another_dingus);
    if (dingus) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Of course, this would work:

```
if (Dingus dingus = another_dingus) { /* */ }
```

But then I'm constructing a `Dingus` and calling `operator=` on it.  It seems logical to me that I would be able to construct the object using whatever constructor I please.

But I'm baffled why this isn't grammatically correct.  I've tested with G++ and MSVC++ and they both complain about this construct, so I'm sure it's part of the spec but I'm curious as to the reasoning for this and what non-ugly workarounds there may be.

Comment: "But then I'm constructing a Dingus and calling operator= on it." No, no assignment occurs. That's just initialization (and happens to use the `=` symbol).

Comment: You know that assignments in conditionals are considerd very, very bad style. Also they are very prone to accidental coding errors. In some languages (like C# or D) assignments are forbidden in coditionals.

Comment: @datenwolf: The actual code will be going in a macro as a way to acquire a resource and test its validity, escaping gracefully if the resource cannot be acquired.  If this construct were valid it would enable me to hide the gory "bad style" stuff behind a terse and readable block-style macro.

Comment: @GMan: Then to expand the question, how would I do this if I wanted to call a constructor explicitly?  `if (Dingus dingus = Dingus(...))`?

Comment: @cdhowie : Yes, that's exactly correct, as Pubby's answer noted.

Comment: @GMan: As pointed out in another answer's comments, using `=` initialization can result in an `operator=` call if the compiler doesn't use constructor eliding.  So if I'm trying to be efficient on compilers that don't support that, using `=` initialization may not be a good option.

Comment: @cdhowie : No, using `=` initialization can result in a _copy-construction_ if the compiler doesn't elide the copy. It is not possible to assign (`operator=`) to an object that has not been constructed.

Comment: @ildjarn: Right, my understanding was that `Dingus foo = bar;` is semantically equivalent to `Dingus foo; foo.operator=(bar);`.  Is there a spec reference I can read up on that defines what happens when you use `=` initialization with objects?

Comment: @ildjarn: Not that I don't trust you of course, I just like doing my own research.  (And this particular question wasn't very google-able.)

Comment: @cdhowie : The C++ standard is not free, but if you don't mind using something _almost_ identical to the standard, there's [N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3234.pdf). Specifically, you want to read about copy-initialization vs. direct-initialization (§8.5).

Comment: @cdhowie: No, that's wrong. (1) `T x(a)` is called *direct-initialization*. This means `x` is constructed directly using a constructor that accepts `a`. (2) `T x = y(a)` is called *copy-initialization*. `x` is constructed from `y` using the copy-constructor, and `y` is directly-initialized. (3) In almost all cases the compiler will turn copy-initialization into direct-initialization, so performance is of no concern. The only issue is that copy-initialization requires `T` be copy-constructable, which isn't always the case.

Comment: @Gman: Is that true even when constructor eliding is disabled or not implemented?

Comment: @cdhowie: Is which point true? 1 and 2 are mandated by the standard, 3 is a common optimization in every modern compiler. (Note that MSVC does 3 wrong, or did in 2008. It would turn copy-initialization into direct-initialization without checking that `T` was copyable.)

Comment: Point 3.  It's an optimization but not a required one.  What I'm saying is that `if (Dingus dingus = foo)` cannot be assumed to compile as copy-constructed; it's legal for a compiler to implement that as default-construction followed by assignment.

Comment: @cdhowie: `The actual code will be going in a macro` - stop sweating it then! Nobody needs to look at that macro. Just code it verbosely, three lines of code extra and grab a beer - wrap the whole shebang in `do { ..... } while(false)` for macro sanity and be merry

Comment: @sehe: I was hoping to have a syntax similar to `WITH_RESOURCE(variablename) { ... }` but every construction I can find will either require `}}` to close the blocks correctly, or will require a macro at the end of the block to hide that detail.  I can't seem to find something that will allow me to construct an object that is destroyed at the end of the block, run a test on that object, take action (log a warning in this case) if the resource cannot be acquired, and be usable with `MACRO() { }` syntax.  I noticed this particular oddity when trying stuff, and thought I'd inquire about it. :)

Comment: @cdhowie Perhaps you can post the real goal as a question. I think this idiom has been solved numerous times and - especially in the presence of C++11 - there is very very little that can't be achieved

Comment: @cdhowie: Huh? It's never legal for a compiler to turn `T x = y` into `T x; x = y;`, I don't know where you got that from.

Comment: @sehe: I probably will, as a separate question.  Unfortunately C++11 isn't available in this environment, so I can't rely on it.

Comment: @GMan: Then what does constructor eliding do?  Is that when you're initializing a variable of type T with the result of a function returning an object of type T?

Comment: @cdhowie: That's one area, yes. It also means `T x = T(a);` can become `T x(a);`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a bit technical. There's no reason why what you want couldn't be allowed, it just isn't. It's the grammar.

An `if` statement is a selection statement, and it takes the grammatical form:

```
if (condition) statement
```

Here, `condition` can be either:

- `expression` or
- `type-specifier-seq declarator = assignment-expression`

And there you have it. Allowing a declaration in a condition is a special case, and it must follow *that* form or your program is ill-formed. They could have probably allow direct-initialization instead of copy-initialization, but there isn't really any motivation to do so now. [As Johannes Schaub points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8332693/87234), this change would break existing code, so it's pretty much never going to happen.

Let_Me_Be notes that C++11 added a third form (I'm ignoring attributes here):

```
decl-specifier-seq declarator braced-init-list
```

So `if (bool b{true})` is fine. (This can't possibly break any valid existing code.)

---

Note your question seems to do with efficiency: don't worry. The compiler will elide the temporary value and just construct the left-hand side directly. This, however, requires your type be copyable (or movable in C++11).

Comment: Interestingly in C++11 `if (bool x{true})` seems to be OK (checked standard, and indeed they added a third line to the condition specification).

Comment: I believe that strictly `if (const noncopyable& nc = noncopyable(5))` is C++11 only too, because - until C++11 - an implementation was allowed to copy the temporary before binding to the `const` reference.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: I think you're right, it's a bit of a muddy area. It *could*, but almost never did (it didn't need to). And I'm not sure that allowance was applied to references. I'm pretty sure `T x = T(...)` could copy the temporary as many times as wanted, but I think with references `const T& x = T(...)` had to bind immediately. But I'm unsure of it all.

Comment: I've checked. It's not muddy at all. `noncopyable(5)` is an _rvalue_ and it is always allowed to do this: "a temporary of type "cv1 T2" [sic] is created, and a constructor is called to copy the entire rvalue object into the temporary. The reference is bound to the temporary or to a sub-object within the temporary." when binding an _rvalue_ to a const ref.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Huh, I thought it was messy, guess not.

Comment: `noncopyable& nc = remove_const(noncopyable(5))` creates a dangling reference.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Right you are, how's that?

Comment: I don't understand this statement: "Technically the temporary can be copied as much as the compiler wants (in C++03), but since the point of using references is to allow noncopyable objects to be declared, it's no worry.". Surely he will get "inaccessible copy constructor" in C++03 (even if no copy is done), so surely it *is* a worry. Or am I missing something important?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I am the dumb one here. :( I sure muddled this up a lot.

Answer (score 5):

It should be noted.that `if(functor(f)(123)) ...;`  would then not be the call of an anonymous functor with argument 123  anymore but would declare a functor initialized by 123.

And i think introducing such pitfalls for that little feature is not worth it.

---

Since it may not be clear what the above means, let's take a deeper look. First remember that parentheses around a declarator are allowed, including for the degenerate case of being directly around a declared name:

```
int(n) = 0; 
// same: int n = 0; 

int(n)(0);
// same: int n(0);
```

Both of the parenthesized versions are ambiguous, because the first could be an assignment and the second could be a function call. But both could also be declarations. And the Standard says that they *are* declarations.

If we will allow paren-initializers in conditions, then we introduce the latter ambiguity into conditions too, just as for the statement case. Thus we would make valid condition expressions that are used nowadays into declarations after the feature is supported. Consider

```
typedef bool(*handler_type)(int);

bool f(int) { /* ... */ }
bool f(int, int) { /* ... */ }

void call_it() {
   // user wants to call f(int), but it is overloaded!
   // -> user tries a cast...
   if(handler_type(f)(0)) {
     /* ... */
   }
}
```

What you think will happen? Of course, it will never enter the `if` body, because it always declares a null pointer. It never calls function `f`. Without the "feature" it will properly call `f`, because we don't have the ambiguity. This is not limited to only `(f)`, but also `(*f)` (declares a pointer), `(&f)` (declares a reference) et al.

Again: Do we want such pitfalls as price for such a small feature? I don't know how many people even know they could declare stuff in a condition.

Comment: I don't think that's true at all, since `f` is in parentheses.  This syntax is unambiguous outside of an `if` condition; why should it be ambiguous inside?

Comment: @cdhowie no the syntax is also ambiguous outside.

Comment: Then, using that reasoning, enlighten me as to why this syntax compiles correctly when used as a statement instead of as a condition.

Comment: @cdhowie testcase? I dont know what code you tested... for starters try `bool x; { bool(x)(123); }` .

Comment: `bool(x)(123)` is not the same thing as `bool x(123)`.  The potential ambiguity in the latter case is between a function prototype and constructor-initialization.  This is disambiguated when the compiler examines contents of the parentheses.  The former case is unambiguously attempting to invoke `operator()` on a `bool` constructed from `x`.

Comment: @cdhowie you did not try my testcase. No, the former case is *not* trying to call a `bool`, but it declares a `bool` variable `x` and initializes it with `123`. I don't feel comfortable with you ignoring what I write in the comments.

Comment: I see, that does indeed work.  However, you in turn are ignoring that `bool x(123)` works just fine *outside* of a conditional.  It may be ambiguous, but the compiler is able to resolve the ambiguity by looking at context.  In other words, whether the expression exists inside of an `if()` conditional or outside does not make it any more or less ambiguous; the compiler is equally capable of disambiguating the expression/statement in both contexts.

Comment: @cdhowie I have not written anything about `bool x(123)`. I will revise my answer (previously written on a phone), perhaps it will be clearer.

Comment: Hmm.  If you aren't writing about the `typename variablename(...)` form, then how is this relevant to the question?

Comment: Ok. I see the problem, but it's not clear how this would be evaluated any differently inside an `if()` condition or as a standalone statement. The ambiguity exists in both cases.

Comment: @cdhowie it is not evaluated any differently if you allow paren initializers in the if condition. Currently they are not allowed, so `bool(x)(123)` in a if condition is ill-formed, but as a statement it is well formed.

Comment: Sure, but if it were allowed in an if condition, why should it be evaluated any differently?

Answer (score 3):

It's language grammar restriction. The bit in parentheses in an `if` statement can either be an *expression* or it can be a restricted form of declaration which must have one of the forms:

> *attribute-specifier-seq* OPT  *decl-specifier-seq*  *declarator* = *initializer-clause*
>
> *attribute-specifier-seq* OPT  *decl-specifier-seq*  *declarator*  *braced-init-list*

No other forms of declaration are allowed. Note that there is no assignment going on here, only copy-initialization.

If you want to direct-initialize an object in a select statement condition you have you use the new form of a *braced-init-list* (since C++11):

```
if (Type var { init })
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Phew, beat you by 27 seconds. :) +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution to your problem, although it doesn't quite answer the question:

```
if (bool b = bool(true)) { /* */ }
```

It's not doing what you think it's doing - bool(true) does not call the constructor in this case, it's performing a cast. For instance:

```
return foo(0);
```

is the same as:

```
return static_cast<foo>(0); // or (foo)0
```

Test:

```
struct foo {
  foo(int x) {
    std::cout << "ctor\n";
  }
  foo(const foo& x) {
    std::cout << "copy ctor\n";
  }
  operator bool() {
    return true;
  }

};

int main(int, char**) {
  if (foo x = foo(1)) { /* */ }
}
```

prints "ctor". Does not call copy constructor due to copy elision.

Comment: That's not a solution, because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: In the context of an object, won't `b` still be default-constructed and then assigned to?  How is this better than `if (bool b = true) { /* */ }`?

Comment: @cdhowie : No, `b` will be copy-constructed in both of those scenarios. As @GMan commented on your question, `=` is not always assignment.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be : It _does_ answer the question -- copy-initialization is the best you can do here (for C++03).

Comment: @ildjarn It doesn't call copy constructor if that's what you mean.

Comment: +1 for the code sample. This isn't a direct answer but it does highlight that part of my question was based on erroneous knowledge and in so doing answers my question in a roundabout way.

Comment: @Pubby : Copy elision can prevent the copy constructor from being called, but it's still copy-initialization so the copy-constructor must be defined and accessible.

Comment: @Puddy: But it might call the copy constructor, it would be legal for an implementation to do so. (If you are using gcc try `-fno-elide-constructors`.)

Answer (score -3):

because "=" is defined as a function that takes two arguments and - after performing its job - it returns the value of the first. The constructor does not return a value.

Comment: Interesting theory. However, this `=` is an initialization rather than an assignment.

Comment: `Dingus dingus = another_dingus` is not an expression, it has no value.

Comment: Not to be argumentative, but C++ follows C and C allowed it because of the usual usage of "=". If "=" didn't usually return a value, the syntax would not have been allowed. Why do some many people feel the need to give smart-alec responses?

Comment: @John : Because in this case it's exactly the distinction between a correct and an incorrect answer. The `if` condition must be an expression, but `=` is a statement, not an expression.

Comment: @John: It's not being a smart-alec, it's desiring to have a factually true answer.

Comment: I don't see any smart-alec responses here. In C or C++, there's a difference between assignment and initialization, even if they both use the `=` symbol. Assignment returns a value and initialization does not. Maybe we misunderstood what you are trying to say.

Comment: @ildjarn: `=` can be a valid part of an assignment expression. `if (c = get())` is valid and there is assignment going on; it's just not the same as the case that's being asked about in the question. The important distiction is that there is a type and a new name being declared, not the presence of `=` itself.

Comment: @Charles : Right, I meant the copy-initialization form of `=`, not the assignment form. I should have been more specific.

Comment: I am quoting this from p296 of "C++ Programming 3rd Edition": int c 1 = s [1 ]; // c1 = s.operator[](1).operator char() . Is this an assignment or an initialisation?

Comment: @sehe: but initialisation isn't c1(s.operator[](1).operator char()) ? kind of buffled there. I mean in the strict sense I would expect initialisation to call the constructor and assignment to call operator=(/* ... */) .

Comment: solved: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr387.htm

Comment: @sehe: you should relax mate. I already posted the link that specifies the answer. Your answer was your answer, and it was non-authorative, nor did you cite any sources to justify your answer, nor you are an authoritative source as far as I know, nor you did justify your answer, it was a plain negation.

Comment: @sehe: Sorry mate, again I don't see your point. I did not disagree with GMan's question. I was wondering if the statement is correct. I have already voted up GMan's solution. The way Stroustrup wrote the comment made thought that it might be a call to operator= instead of a call to the constructor. I clarify that it is not a call with the citation. I seemed to touch a soft spot there, I apologise...cheer up, this is not a contest.