# How to read from a text file and split sentences apart in C

Tags: c++, file, tree

I want to read a series of questions from a text file. Each question is separated by a comma, so I am thinking that I have to check for each character to not be equal to a comma before copying the character?

The text file looks something like this "Is it red?, Is it bigger than a mailbox?, Is it an animal?"

In case it affects the code, I want to copy each string into a node to put in a tree later on.

```
while (fgets(stringPtr, 100, filePtr) != ',')
   strcpy(stringPtr, treeNode);
```

Is something like this ok?

Comment: You should tag as C or C++, not both.  (If you list C you'll almost certainly be able to use the solution in C++, but not vice versa.)

Answer (score 2):

Given your description - something like the follow:

```
std::string question_string;
std::set<std::string> my_tree;

if (std::ifstream file_stream{filename})
{
    while (std::getline(file_stream, question_string, ','))
        my_tree.insert(question_string);
}
else
    std::cerr << "unable to open " << filename << '\n';
```

You'll need to get the filename from somewhere, include the relevant headers (google the classes if you need to).

Comment: Good answer! I correct a little mistake, in 'if' statement.

Comment: @CodeDreamer: someone rejected, but well spotted - I should have used `{` and `}` around `filename`....  Cheers.

Comment: @TonyD I did check and using () is refused by the compiler. You also want to see some kind of return variable - so this is not a constructor. But what is it?

Comment: @KlaasvanGend the curly braces are the new C++11 initialisation syntax, surrounding the arguments to the constructor.  It's explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332285/why-cant-variables-defined-in-a-conditional-be-constructed-with-arguments)  Anyway, it is a constructor call - you're allowed to create new objects in certain flow-control statements e.g. `if (T* p = get())`, `for (iterator i = c.begin(), e = c.end(); i != e; ++i) ...`.  If your compiler doesn't support this syntax, then just use `std::ifstream file_stream(filename); if (file_stream) { ... }`.